# How to free a member of an array from memory allocation one by one

Tags: c++, malloc, free

I have a code that goes like this:

```
void push(char *buffer, char entry, int length)
{
    buffer[length] = entry;
}
void main(void)
{
    char * buffer = new char;
    int length, x;


    cout << "How many: ";
    cin >> length;

    x = length;

    buffer = (char*)malloc(length + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        char entry;
        cout << "Input: ";
        cin >> entry;
        push(buffer, entry, i);
    }

    for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        free(&buffer[i]);
        cout << "Success in Removing: " << buffer[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

I need to free the last member of array entered one by one. But I keep getting a breakpoint error. How should I do this?

Comment: With the exception of `cout`, `cin` and `new` (which has no `delete` as far as I can see), all of these is basically C, not C++.

Comment: sorry.. please don't mind the `new`. I used `malloc` here.

Comment: `free` doesn't work like that.  You can only call `free` on a pointer that was returned by a `malloc`-family function.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You've allocated a single block of memory and you have to free it as a single block. BTW: you lose the pointer from the first `new` you did and leak that memory.

Comment: @nix I am trying to free each member of array from the last entry. The Stack Data Structure. So, how can I free each member of array?

Comment: You do not need to use new and malloc. Pick one! `new char[length + 1];` and remove the malloc. Then use 'delete buffer' instead of free

Comment: What they are trying to tell you is that **you can't do that**. The end.

Comment: @Ralph De Guzman: You don't need to free each member; they weren't allocated separately.  You only allocated an array; you just need to free that.

Comment: If you want a Stack Data Structure which behaves in that way, perhaps use `std::stack<_pointer_>` :)...or even a `std::vector<_pointer_>` will do.

Comment: My exercise is to simulate my own Stack data structure. I am not to use the `stack` and `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Make this change and try it-

```
for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    buffer[i]='\0'; // you can't free one memory location in array of memory
    cout << "Success in Removing: " << buffer[i] << endl;
}
```

In this way only you can remove that last member from your array. After removing every thing `delete` the memory.

Comment: It's not removed, it's just `\0`. Granted, this might be correct if the OP is working with strings, but the element is still present.

Comment: I removed the last member then after the loop, I freed the array. I guess this is best when I use array of struct. Am I right?

Comment: @RalphDeGuzman this is best when you use array of characters(strings).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but it hurts my eyes...

```
void push(char *buffer, char entry, int length)
{
    buffer[length] = entry;
}
void main(void)
{
    char * buffer; // Nothing to do here
    int length, x;


    cout << "How many: ";
    cin >> length;

    x = length;

    // buffer = (char*)malloc(length);
    // Better
    buffer = new char[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        char entry;
        cout << "Input: ";
        cin >> entry;
        push(buffer, entry, i);
    }

    for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        buffer[i] = '\0'; // I assume this is some sort of char stack displayable as a string...
        cout << "Success in Removing: " << buffer[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] buffer;
}
```

If you are doing a char stack you should probably keep track of the last unsued index or better, use a stack.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the advice. We already have the same code. Just edited a moment after I post my question here. Thanks still.

Comment: +1 Few nits: the whole "removing" business is a matter for the application to define... if you want to use '\0' (the NUL/0 character) as a sentinel value marking unusued array entries, the code presented here's good, but in general if you're about to `delete[]` the buffer there's no need to do anything to the individual characters therein beforehand.  Separately, `new char[length + 1]` makes a larger buffer than required, presumably so there'll be space for a NUL terminator, but you're never doing anything needing one e.g. `std::cout << buffer << '\n';`, and this code doesn't populate one.

Comment: @TonyD Good point, i removed unnecessary `+ 1` for this code, thanks.